# How to return Model Method as Response in api

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-9, laravel-api

I have a method called `show` at the Product Model which returns a resource for api results:

```
public function show(Product $product): ProductResource
    {
        return (new ProductResource($product))->additional([
            'gallery' => $product->photos->pluck('image')
                ->transform(fn ($v) => Storage::disk('public')->url($v))
        ]);
    }
```

Now I have defined a method called `similarProductsBasedOnBrand` at the Product Model which goes like this:

```
public function similarProductsBasedOnBrand($brand_id)
    {
        return Category::find($brand_id)->products()->get();
    }
```

But don't know how to get results from this method in api result of `show()`!

So if you know how to return the results of `similarProductsBasedOnBrand` in the response of `show` method, please let me know... I really need this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this

```
$categories = Category::find($brand_id)->products()->get()
return response()->json($categories,200)
```